# Removing spacing for multiple inline citations

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, atbegshi

I am using the package `atbegshi` to compile my bibliography. However, for multiple inline citations, I keep getting [1, 2] when I really wanted [1,2]. I have tried removing the spacing between the comma and my second citation but it seems that the presence of comma will induce the spacing. How should I proceed?

Edit: A minimal working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys, biblabel=brackets]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Porceed by providing a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) for us to play around with. We need to know what citation methods/styles/packages you're using. I doublt `atbegshi` has anything to do with how multiple citations are styled, but other packages might.

Comment: `atbegshi` should have no influence on your citations at all. (Theoretically it is possible that it causes some changes to citations, but that is extremely unlikely.) In order to help you properly we need to know how you generate your citations (which citation/bibliography packages do you load? which style do you use?). This is best shown in a small example document that reproduces your citation and bibliography setup with as little excess code as possible (sometimes called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: @frabjous I have included a MWE. I am using XeLaTex to compile.

Comment: @moewe I have included a MWE as requested.

Comment: That is not a MWE, there is no document class. Curious here, what is the purpose of the atbegshi in this example?

Comment: @daleif I have added in the document class that I am using. There is no real specific purpose of using atbegshi; it is just some package that I know that works to help give me the bibliography.

Comment: I cannot see that helping anything what do ever here. Also you have no citations in this example. And that addcontentsline should be unnecessary with biblatex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638490/removing-spacing-for-multiple-inline-citations?noredirect=1#comment1591855_638490) I fail to see how `atbegshi` would help with the bibliography here. In fact the document better without it (the code will remove the first page, which at least in my example contains the citations we want to see). Note also that you can get rid of the whole `\cleardoublepage\phantomsection\addcontentsline` malarkey if you pass the option `heading=bibintoc,` to `\printbibliography`. The empty `\AtBeginBibliography{}` is also unnecessary.

But now to your question: The comma between citations is controlled by `\multicitedelim`, which is a comma plus a space in `style=numeric,`. If you want to get rid of the space, use the following redefinition

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys, biblabel=brackets]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{sigfridsson,worman}


\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1,2]]